# Need help getting NGen back into working condition

Tags: .net, clr, ngen

NGen is unhappy on my computer, and i can't find a way to get a deep understanding of what is going wrong.

After every startup, ngen logs this message:

> .NET Runtime Optimization Service
>   (clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32) -
>   Service reached limit of transient
>   errors. Will shut down. Last error
>   returned from Service Manager:
>   0x8000ffff.

And when i try to start the optimization service at the commandline i get that same error logged again.

I managed to start the ngen service and immediately pause the queue (by writing a two line batch file, like this:

> net start 
>   clr_optimization_v2.0.50727_32
>
> ngen  queue pause

so now i tried clearing out the queue, by executing items at different status levels, like this:

> ngen executequeueditems 3 /nologo
>   /verbose

but the result is always:

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

...along the way i've uninstalled/re-installed visual studio 2008.
And i've uninstalled SQL server 2005, and i've run the 'system file checker':
 sfc /scannow

Running short of ideas, and would love help from an ngen expert.

How do i get info such as 
"What's causing these catastrophic failures?"
 (note that the /verbose option doesn't increase the amount of info I find out.
"What files are in the queue to be generated?" -- Can I remove some of those files, or pin the blame on a particular file...

Uninstalling and reinstalling the .net framework 2.0 isn't easy, as this is vista and it's a protected part of the operating system.

Update:
i've also tried the advice offered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/f56cc6e4-c2bf-490c-b87b-3e22b1e6b935/) (and mentioned in the first reply) -- but i just get the same catastrophic failure message.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>ngen
>   executequeueditems /nologo
>   Catastrophic failure (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: I smell an OS reinstall in your future..

Comment: this sucks.  I have the same issue with installing MVC ASP.net RC2
Anyone got a solution for fixing ngen?

Comment: Hi Harry -- Phil Haack's description here might be helpful. 
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/05/troubleshooting-installers.aspx
I eventually used Orca.exe to remove the ngen step from the MVC installer.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to this part of the question:

> "What's causing these catastrophic
>   failures?"

There's two log files that can help answer this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.log
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen_service.log
```

(As well as the usual application log, though it is less helpful)

In answer to:

> "What files are in the queue to be
>   generated?"

The usual answer is that this can be seen by running:

```
ngen.exe display
```

(Though in my case it only returns

```
NGEN Roots:    
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

)

Comment: How was this an 'Answer' to the problem?  By ticking this you are just stopping other answers

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/f56cc6e4-c2bf-490c-b87b-3e22b1e6b935/):

> The .NET Runtime Optimization Service
>   attempts to re-try compilation of
>   assemblies when it runs into what it
>   believes are transient errors;
>   examples include RPC errors,
>   out-of-memory errors etc. However,
>   after it has tried to compile the same
>   assembly 20 times and has still failed
>   to do so, it outputs the message above
>   and shuts down. I see that you've
>   already tried to uninstall .NET
>   Framework 2.0 from your machine and
>   re-install it, but that you still have
>   this error. I am guessing that trying
>   to repair the install doesn't help
>   either. Can you possibly try to run
>   "ngen.exe ExecuteQueuedItems" followed
>   by "ngen.exe Update" from
>   %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\?
>   That will attempt to compile all
>   assemblies that don't yet have
>   any/up-to-date 32-bit NGen images
>   synchronously without going through
>   the optimization service. Once the
>   update command completes, can you once
>   again try starting the service and
>   checking to see whether you still get
>   the same message in the system log? If
>   this problem is not specific to the
>   service, I expect that you will see
>   compilation errors in the command-line
>   output as well.

Comment: hi bobby. i updated the question to mention what happened when i tried this. (it failed, but took over 256 chars to explain that ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (installing Asp MVC 1.0).
Looking for the answer I've spotted [Haacked Blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/05/troubleshooting-installers.aspx) where some reasons have been explained.
Having spent 2 hours of trying to solve this I was so frustrated that I have used

```
ngen /delete *
```

It worked. But i'm not sure if it wouldn't make small disaster ;/

Maybe this will help..

Comment: Good work kliszaq! Please report back if "ngen /delete *" leads to any other issues for you.

Comment: I have not noticed yet any bad issues of this soultion. Even "if", it is not a problem for me because I'am to upgrade my Vista to Windows 7 in the next week.